# Stubbing express middleware functions with sinon is

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, sinon

### Description

I try to set stub fakes for a express middleware function and it's not replacing over.

### What I'm trying (how to reproduce)

I'm trying to use sinon stubbing via `callsFake` function, just as it's advised from their most updated docs.

Even though I'm requiring the module and replacing the function from the property at the export. I keep seeing the original function behavior acting.

I know that I should try to get the function stubbed before the middleware functions get setup, and that's when express `app` is first imported.

This is the function I'm trying to stub, defined as a function and exported as a object too. It's defined in a script file with a path like `api/middlewares/stripe/signature`.

```
const stripeHelper = require('../../../lib/stripe')
const logger = require('../../../lib/logger')
const verifySignature = (req, res, next) => {
  var event
  let eventName = req.url.replace('/', '')
  try {
      // Try adding the Event as `request.event`
    event = stripeHelper.signatureCheck(
        eventName,
        req.body,
        req.headers['stripe-signature']
      )
  } catch (e) {
      // If `constructEvent` throws an error, respond with the message and return.
    logger.error('Error while verifying webhook request signature', e.message, e)
    return res.status(400).send('Webhook Error:' + e.message)
  }
  req.event = event
  next()
}
module.exports.verifySignature = verifySignature
```

### What I tried already

- Use decache to make sure the express app instance is pristine and it's not being initialized with previous original middleware
- Set multiple `beforEach` hooks in order to organize my stubs and preconditions or test

### What keeps happening

- The original middleware function gets executed
- I don't see any logs of the stub functions (as second proof that sinon stub is not working

This is my stubs and test hooks setup:

```
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
const dirtyChai = require('dirty-chai')
const sinon = require('sinon')
const decache = require('decache')
const signatureMiddleware = require('../../../api/middlewares/stripe/signature')
const bp = require('body-parser')
let verifySignatureStub, rawStub

chai.should()
chai.use(dirtyChai)
chai.use(chaiHttp)

const API_BASE = '/api/subscriptions'
const planId = 'NYA-RUST-MONTHLY'
const utils = require('../../utils')
const {
  hooks: {createSubscription, emitPaymentSucceeded},
  stripe: {generateEventFromMock}
} = utils

let testUser, testToken, testSubscription, server

describe.only('Subscriptions renewal (invoice.payment_succeeded)', function () {
  this.timeout(30000)

  beforeEach(function (done) {
    createSubscription(server, {planId}, function (err, resp) {
      if (err) return done(err)
      const {user, jwt, subscription} = resp
      console.log(user, jwt)
      testUser = user
      testToken = jwt
      testSubscription = subscription
      done()
    })
  })

  beforeEach(function (done) {
    verifySignatureStub = sinon.stub(signatureMiddleware, 'verifySignature')
    rawStub = sinon.stub(bp, 'raw')
    rawStub.callsFake(function (req, res, next) {
      console.log('bp raw')
      return next()
    })
    verifySignatureStub.callsFake(function (req, res, next) {
      const {customerId} = testUser.stripe
      const subscriptionId = testSubscription.id
      console.log('fake verify')
      req.event = generateEventFromMock('invoice.payment_failed', {subscriptionId, customerId, planId})
      return next()
    })
    done()
  })

  beforeEach(function (done) {
    decache('../../../index')
    server = require('../../../index')
    const {customerId} = testUser.stripe
    const {id: subscriptionId} = testSubscription
    console.log(`emitting payment succeeded with ${customerId}, ${subscriptionId} ${planId}`)
    emitPaymentSucceeded(server, testToken, function (err, response) {
      if (err) return done(err)
      done()
    })
  })

  afterEach(function (done) {
    verifySignatureStub.restore()
    done()
  })

  it('Date subscription will renew gets set to a valid number roughly one month', function () {
    // Not even getting here becasue calling the original function contains verifyMiddleware which should be replaced
  })

  it('Current period end is modified')

  it('An invoice for the new starting period is generated')

  it('Subscription status keeps active')
})
```

**Context (please complete the following information):**

All runs over Node 8 and I'm running tests with mocha and did a set up with dirty chai.

These are my dev dependencies:

`"devDependencies": {
    "base64url": "^2.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "decache": "^4.4.0",
    "dirty-chai": "^2.0.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "google-auth-library": "^0.12.0",
    "googleapis": "^23.0.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.0",
    "nyc": "^11.2.1",
    "sinon": "^6.1.5",
    "standard": "^10.0.3",
    "stripe-local": "^0.1.1"
  }`

### Open issue

https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1889

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, stubs should be set up per test, i.e. in `beforeEach` or `it`, not in `before`. Here they don't seem to contain per-test logic but they can, and in this case they won't work as expected with `before`. `mocha-sinon` should preferably be used to integrate Mocha with Sinon sandbox, so no `afterEach` is needed to restore stubs, this is done automatically.

Since `verifySignature` is export property and not the export itself, `signatureMiddleware` module may be left as is, but modules that use it should be de-cached and re-imported in tests where they are expected to use `verifySignature`. If the behaviour should be same for entire test suite, this should be performed in `beforeEach` as well. E.g. if these middlewares are used in `app` module directly, it's:

```
const decache = require('decache');

...

  describe(() => {
    let app;

    beforeEach(() => {
      verifySignatureStub = sinon.stub(signatureMiddleware, 'verifySignature');
      ...
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      decache('./app');
      app = require('./app');
    });
```

Comment: So from your perspective is ok to have multiple `beforeEach` hooks?

Comment: It's surely ok to have multiple beforeEach in Mocha or other unit test frameworks, this allows to compose blocks, also the ones from parent `describe`.